# Is it correct and natural to say "the movies is showing a great movie today"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to say *the movies is showing a great movie today*? For example:

> Let's go catch a movie today. **The movies is showing** a great movie about space today.

If it doesn't sound right, what would you say?

Comment: In British English, I would say "Let's go and see a film. [Name of cinema] is showing a great film about space today" or "There's a great film on at [name of cinema]."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not a good way to say what you want to say.  The phrase "the movies", unless there is actually a theater called "The Movies" is incorrect.

I suggest that you might say:

"Let's go catch a movie today.  They are showing a great film about space today."